# How to divide by zero without error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, floating-point, nan

i need to obtain float NaN and infinity, but i can't use such constructions

```
0. / 0.
1. / 0.
```

because it cause compile time

> error C2124: divide or mod by zero

EDIT, it is cool to have answers for where i can get this numbers (+1 for every), but is it possible to divide by zero?

Comment: Math fact: It's not possible to divide by 0.

Comment: Why do you want to divide by zero? Your compiler might have a flag to allow this. It isn't a compiler error on my platform.

Comment: This question perfectly highlights why when someone asks a seemingly weird question, we must come back with: "Uhm, what are you trying to **achieve**? Don't tell us your *solution*. Tell us your *problem*."

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Floating-point fact: `1. / 0.` is defined as `+inf` and `0. / 0.` is defined as `NaN`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply return a NaN or an infinity, for example:

```
return std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
```

or

```
return std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
```

See [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), from header `<limits>`.

Comment: All located in the header `<limits>`

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz I added that, and a link to a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Use [std::numeric_limits::infinity()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) and [std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) or [std::numeric_limits::signaling_NaN()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/signaling_NaN) from `<limits>`.